# Memcached в php не получает данные - причина?

Tags: php, memcached

Ситуация:

```
$memcache_obj->set("11111$rndnum", $play_uni[1][$rrr]."2385942236754".$play_uni[2][$rrr], false, 14000);
$id_d2 = $memcache_obj->get("11111$rndnum");
loger("????? $rndnum ----- $id_d2");
```

Результат: лог-файл содержит информацию вида

```
????? 92245444678481174 ----- 
????? 74244766301724645 ----- 
????? 99933590860933665 ----- 
????? 90245545269794683 ----- 
????? 80779539452917708 ----- 
????? 15259308091664450 ----- 
????? 04532884780488429 ----- 
????? 81288269812162196 ----- 
????? 05829188611602986 ----- 9c834261702bda1fe1cc8d398695318123859422367545094321
????? 88381371446510567 ----- 5483a50ebde98bfec3af4ffc967e970223859422367545329085
```

95% данных не извлекается из кеша.

Нагрузка на сайт: 100 000 посетителей в день, параметры мемкеша:

2690775 - элементов memcache закешировано

5011MB - мегабайт memcache закешировано

30720MB - количество мегабайт, которые этот сервер может использовать для хранения

5 - количество открытых соединений

259 - количество структур соединений, выделенных сервером

9027642 - совокупное количество запросов на получение

3271828 - накопительное количество запросов на хранение

6425732 - количество ключей, которые были запрошены и найдены

2601910 - количество элементов, которые были запрошены и не найдены

5521MB - общее количество мегабайт, считанных этим сервером из сети

17174MB - общее количество мегабайт, отправленных этим сервером в сеть